# What is the best way to prevent to see "options are not unique" error?

Tags: http-headers, shopify

When I want to update a specific product how can I determine non unique options and prevent to see 'options are not unique' error?

This is xml of create product:

```
my $xml = qq~<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<product>
<title>$title</title>
<body-html>$description</body-html>
<vendor>$vendor</vendor>
<product-type>$product_type</product-type>
<published type="boolean">$publish_status</published>~;
$xml.=qq{<variants type="array">
<variant>
      <title>$title</title>
  <option1>$title</option1>
  <option2 nil="true"></option2>
  <option3 nil="true"></option3>};
$xml.=qq{<price>$price</price>
  <sku>$sku</sku>
  <position type="integer">1</position>
 </variant>
</variants>};
$xml.='</product>';
```

This is the xml of modify product:

```
my $xml = qq~<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<product>~;

$xml.=qq~<title>$title</title>~;
$xml.=qq~<id type="integer">$id_product</id>~;
$xml.=qq~<body-html>$description</body-html>
<vendor>$vendor</vendor>
<product-type>$product_type</product-type>
<published type="boolean">$publish_status</published>
<variants type="array">
  <variant>~;
$xml.= qq~<title>$title</title>~;
$xml.= qq~<option1>$title</option1>~;
$xml.= qq~<option2 nil="true"/>~;
$xml.= qq~<option3 nil="true"/>~;
$xml.=qq~<price>$price</price>
  <sku>$sku</sku>
  <position type="integer">1</position>
</variant>
</variants>~;
$xml.='</product>';
```

I am getting "options are not unique" error when I try to modify specific product. option1 tag content is same as previous option1 tag content. Is it a bug? or option1 value is must be different previous one? What I have to do not see "options are not unique" error?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a bug in the API when updating products and you are passing in an option that already exists.  The error message is actually quite misleading and is being worked on at the moment.

Comment: Hi csaunders, is the bug solved?  How can I create a product with more than 1 option via the API?

Comment: Nope.  The issue seemed trivial on the surface but there's a bit of work that needs to be done so we haven't had the chance to properly fix it yet.

Comment: @csaunders 10 years on and it seems this bug still exists ..